# Android Data Binding using include tag

Tags: java, android, data-binding, android-button, android-databinding

### Update note:

The above example **works properly**, because release 1.0-rc4 **fixed** the issue of needing the unnecessary variable.

### Original question:

I do exactly as it is described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes) and it does not work:

**main.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:andr...
    <data>
    </data>
       <include layout="@layout/buttons"></include>
....
```

**buttons.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:andr...>
    <data>
    </data>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        ...." />
```

**MyActivity.java:**

```
 ... binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate...
binding.button; ->cannot resolve symbol 'button'
```

how to get button?

Comment: like updated
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The problem is that the included layout isn't being thought of as a data-bound layout. To make it act as one, you need to pass a variable:

**buttons.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:andr...>
  <data>
    <variable name="foo" type="int"/>
  </data>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    ... />
```

**main.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:andr...
   ...
   <include layout="@layout/buttons"
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            app:foo="@{1}"/>
   ...
```

Then you can access buttons indirectly through the buttons field:

```
MainBinding binding = MainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
binding.buttons.button
```

As of 1.0-rc4 (just released), you no longer need the variable. You can simplify it to:

**buttons.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:andr...>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    ... />
```

**main.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:andr...
   ...
   <include layout="@layout/buttons"
            android:id="@+id/buttons"/>
   ....
```

Comment: 1.0-rc4 now fixes the problem of needing the unnecessary variable. You can now use simply: `<include layout="@layout/buttons" android:id="@+id/buttons"/>`. You still need the id so that it will produce a public field for you so that you can access the Button View.

Comment: Are anyone else having problems binding click events on the layout though?

Comment: Are you using data binding syntax? `android:onClick="@{myObj.clickHandler}"`

Comment: Databinding with include support. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#includes

Comment: Main point to remember here is to get the button reference, you need to do `binding.{id of include tag}.button` instead of `binding.button`. Took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: @GeorgeMount How to call static method from layout element like `android:text="{MyClass.getUser().name}"` ?

Comment: You can do that either by importing the class name using the `<import type="com.example.MyClass"/>` in the `data` section or by using the fully qualified class name in the expression: `android:text="@{com.example.MyClass.user.name}"`

Comment: what if you want to pass in two parameters/

Comment: If you want to pass two parameters, you can just do that. `<include layout="..." app:param1="@{1}" app:param2="@{2}"/>` where `param1` and `param2` are variables in your included layout.

Comment: Apologies, would you care to type the entire layout? This '...' all over the place is pretty much unreadable. Like I don't understand if I still include <merge> tag?

Comment: @NeonWarge There is a complete example at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#imports_variables_and_includes. It adds "Data binding doesn't support include as a direct child of a merge element"

Comment: I've got an error message that says: "Only one layout element and one data element are allowed"

Comment: @GeorgeMount it doesn't work for me with "app" namespace. It has to be "bind" namespace for it to generate correct code. Like this: `bind:foo={something}`

Comment: I had to clean/rebuild because I switched over from findViewById.

Comment: Note that `foo` or any other name you choose must be **lowercase**.

Comment: @Patrick no matter, its work.

Answer (score 78):

#### Easy Complete Example

> Just set `id` to included layout, and use `binding.includedLayout.anyView`.

**This example helps passing a value to `<include` & accessing included views in code.**

#### Step 1

You have **`layout_common.xml`**, want to pass `String` to included layout.

You will create `String` variable in layout and refer this `String` to `TextView`.

```
<data>
    // declare fields
    <variable
        name="passedText"
        type="String"/>
</data>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    ...
    android:text="@{passedText}"/> //set field to your view.
```

#### Step 2

Include this layout to parent layout. Give an **`id`** to included layout, so that we can use that in binding class. Now you can pass String `passedText` to your `<include` tag.

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        ..
        >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/includedLayout"
            layout="@layout/layout_common"
            app:passedText="@{@string/app_name}" // here we pass any String 
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

- You can use now `binding.includedLayout.textView` in your class.
- You can pass any variables to included layout like above.

  ```
  ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
  binding.includedLayout.textView.setText("text");
  ```

**Note** Both layouts (parent & included) should be `binding layout`, wrapped with `<layout`

Comment: In your answer you handled the setText event programmatically ,Instead of TextView if it would have been a Button , then how would you have handled its click event .I know that programmatically  `binding.includedLayout.button.setOnClickListener` would be the alternative,but what if i want to use `onClick` attribute in XML itself ?

Comment: You can pass `OnClickListener` to included layout. even you can pass anything in binding. Check this answer, if you need more help, let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51722829/6891563

Comment: When I do this, I just get a blank field for `passedText`. The only difference is I don't include the MainActivity code because I just want to pass the string resource in <include> and leave it like that. Why is it always blank though?

Comment: @Elliptica As its databinding, I guess the value for `passedText` should be an `ObservableField` or a LiveData, otherwise it will never be actually loaded, right @Khemraj?

Comment: This doesn't compile.  `Error: cannot find symbol`

Answer (score 24):

just set an id for your include layout

```xml
    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        layout="@layout/buttons" />
```

then

```java
BUTTONSBINDING binding = yourMainBinding.layout;
```

`BUTTONSBINDING` is res/layout/buttons.xml

now :

```java
binding.button.setText("simple_Way");
```

Comment: Thanks for getting the point. Above answers bury the lead.

Comment: This was the correct answer for today's days. Thank you sr

Answer (score 6):

You can make your bind work on your include just adding a ID to it like so:

```
<include
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            layout="@layout/loading_layout"
            bind:booleanVisibility="@{viewModel.showLoading}" />
```

Answer (score 5):

An other interesting thing on this is that you can pas variables to the imported layout from the binder like this:

```
MainBinding binding = MainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
binding.buttons.setVariable(BR.varID, variable)
```

Comment: This was the only solution that ended up working for me, otherwise I get kept receiving the error "error: cannot find symbol this.totalAmtContainer.setMonthly_amt(monthlyAmt);"

with my variable name being "monthlyAmt"

Answer (score 0):

it seems you have empty data tag in your xml file please cross check, it is making cause to not generate include layout file

```
 <data>

</data>
```

remove this tag if your not using, will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add, I had the similar problem.
My problem was that the variable name was title, the same as id name.
There was no compile error. (Not 100% sure was that a problem, I also clean the project)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<data>

    <variable
        name="title"
        type="String" />
</data>
...
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/title"...>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
...
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you make sure your include layout has enabled dataBinding tag

below code is my layout that I include in other layout

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="backBinding"
        type="String" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cl_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_30"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_30"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_back"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_20"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_back"
        style="@style/AidoFTTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:text="@string/face_training"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_20"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iv_back"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_back"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iv_back" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here I am including in my main layout

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.ingenDynamic.coreaidokotlin.viewModels.VideoCallViewModel" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/aido_main_background"
    tools:context=".ui.aidoVideoCall.ContactActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/back_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_20"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_appBar">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/back"
            layout="@layout/app_back_layout"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and directly I can access my included layout

```
binding.backLayout.setOnClickListener { finish() }
binding.back.tvBack.text = getText(R.string.video_call)
```