# How to access view inside a included layout using data binding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have content_main layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and activity_main

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        app:foo="@{1}">
    </include>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

Now in the Java I have

```
ActivityMainBinding binding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);
```

Now I want to access the textview inside the content_main as

```
binding.content.textView
```

I tried having content_main in a layout tag but it did not work.
I also followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag) but it did not work

How can I do that?

Comment: In the link that you've referred, there is a mention that with version 1.0-rc4 it should just work without passing fake variables, but you need to have the root `<layout>` tag in both files. I don't see this tag in your content_main.xml layout.

Comment: Thank you @maciej you are right I did have the layout tag in the original code but  I solved the issue by rebuilding the project

Answer (score 2):

Check this

> hello_world.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <include
                android:id="@+id/included"
                layout="@layout/included_layout"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

> included_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/world"/>
</layout>
```

In your java file

```
HelloWorldBinding binding =
    HelloWorldBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
binding.hello.setText(“Hello”);
binding.included.world.setText(“World”);
```

The pattern for included files follows the same pattern as for Views: the ID of the  tag is used as its field name in the class. The included layout has generated its own class with its own fields for the Views in its layout.

Simple as you see.[Source](https://medium.com/google-developers/android-data-binding-that-include-thing-1c8791dd6038#.9dadcxec1)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by rebuilding the project and also you should have the layout tag in content_main XML too