# DataBinding library include don't work without variable

Tags: android, android-databinding

As George Mount [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32958608/1546975)  starting from 1.0-rc4 we no longer need the variable in include when using data binding:

buttons.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:andr...>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    ...." />
```

main.xml:

```
<layout xmlns:andr...
...
    <include layout="@layout/buttons"
            android:id="@+id/buttons"/>
....
```

But I tried it and get error:

**Error:(10, 31) Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. toolbarViewModel is missing it**

I have the included toolbar:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data class="LoginPhoneFragmentBinding">

        <variable
            name="toolbarViewModel"
            type="ru.mobileup.myalarm2.binding.ToolbarViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
             layout="@layout/toolbar"
             android:id="@+id/toolbarBinding"/>
```

And toolbar layout is:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeOverlay"
    app:navigationIcon="@{toolbarViewModel.navigationIconResId}"
    app:navigationOnClickListener="@{toolbarViewModel.navigationOnClickListener}"
    app:title="@{toolbarViewModel.title}"
    app:menu="@{toolbarViewModel.menuResId}"
    app:menuListener="@{toolbarViewModel.onMenuItemClickListener}"/>
```

**What is wrong?**

*Note: I know that with passed variable all works fine. I trying to figure out how use that George mentioned.*

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the databinding library..? The implementation has been [changed](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#build_environment). Please also post the relevant `Java`code. :)

Comment: Hi, I use the 2.0.0-beta4 plugin, and switch binding on using `dataBinding { enabled = true }`. So I think this is the latest for now.
@Amy, I think java is not needed here, because you can reproduce it with just toolbar title passed in first layout as ObservableField, and you will see the same result.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding George's answer on the linked post; you still need the variable if you want to reference it with `@{toolbarViewModel.title}` as you do in your included toolbar layout.

If you have dataBinding enabled in your build.gradle and wrap your layout in an extra `<layout>` tag you'll get an automatically generated `ViewDataBinding` class that contains resolved references to any views that have IDs in your layout (e.g. `binding.toolbar`, or something like that).  This won't automatically bind your data for you, but will allow you to get rid of any `findViewById` calls.

See [his blog post here](https://medium.com/google-developers/no-more-findviewbyid-457457644885#.khj4uvph0) for more information.

Comment: Yep, I think you are right. This was misunderstanding. Just read his answer again and now I see that he is talking only about the ids and from 1.0-rc4 there is just no need to pass variable to get the view by id as binding.buttons.button1 as it was before the mentioned version.