# Databinding error: Only one layout element and one data element are allowed.

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm getting following error when using databinding and include tag inside:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingProcessLayoutsBetaDebug'.>data binding error msg:Only one layout element and one data element are allowed. [path to file] has 3file:[path to file]****\ data binding error ****
```

This is my layout file:

```
[...]

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_description_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_description_header_bottom"
                layout="@layout/activity_description_header_bottom" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_description_contact_info"
                layout="@layout/activity_description_contact_info" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_description_other_info_box"
                layout="@layout/activity_description_other_info_box" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/activity_description_bottom_buttons"
                layout="@layout/activity_description_bottom_buttons" />
        </LinearLayout>
[...]
</layout>
```

And in each of the included layouts i have something like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
[...]
</layout>
```

From this reply: [Android Data Binding using include tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag) i suppose that my code is correct, why databinder thinks that I use more than single tag in the file?

Comment: Off the cuff, it would appear that `<include>` can only integrate widgets (possibly with data binding expressions) as classic layout resources. Any `<layout>` and `<data>` elements would have to be in the top-level resource, the one with the `<include>` elements. That wouldn't be a surprising limitation IMHO, though it would be somewhat disappointing.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I solved my issue. This error appears when there is more than single element in the layout tag:

Wrong:

```
<layout>
     <data>
          ...
     </data>
     <LinearLayout>
          ...
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout>
          ...
     </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Correct:

```
<layout>
     <data>
          ...
     </data>
     <LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout>
              ...
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout>
              ...
         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: If this resolves your issue, mark it as accepted so your question doesn't show up in Unanswered ;)

Comment: Each included layout file must have `<layout><merge>...</merge></layout>`

Comment: Wow this one's great! I built just with the `<layout>` and `<data>` tags alone implemented, without any design elements being implemented further. And I encountered this error. Works fine after implementing design elements to the layout. So, now I've learned not to build and test binding without any design elements.

Answer (score 4):

In < layout>, must have one < data> and one layoutView(Relative/Linear etc)....
Multiple layoutViews are not allowed,In layoutViews may have multiple layoutViews but on top layer multiplicity are not allowed....

Answer (score 2):

layout tag doesn't allow more than one child, Please put your all xml code inside any parent layout like relative/ linear layout

Example

```
<layout>

 <LinearLayout> 
................
............... 
</LinearLayout> 
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2):

- ViewBinding only one layout element is allowed.
- DataBinding only one layout element and one data element are allowed.

### build.gradle (:mobile)

```
android {
    //...

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Do not use `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` as attributes of the `<layout/>` tag because otherwise dataBinding already counts it as a view and then in the scope of layot we could not put another view.

### test.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- ... -->

    </View>

</layout>
```

GL

Answer (score 1):

Also this error hapens when you are using DataBinding and using tag  without tag

correct

```
<layout>
 <data>
      <variable>
      </variable>
 </data>
 <LinearLayout>
      ...
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout>
      ...
 </LinearLayout>
```

in other words you have to keap DataBinding structure in xml