# android data binding <include> layout OnClick listener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a data binding layout that contains a frame layout with `<include>` of other layout inside:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/global_actions_frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.075"
    android:background="@color/colorToolBar">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/included"
        layout="@layout/global_actions">
    </include>
</FrameLayout>
```

the layout has image buttons inside in this format:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_36dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/colorToolBar"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:onClick="@{listener::onClickState}"
android:alpha="0.4"/>
```

and I added the  tag around them and I added data with  name of activity

```
 <data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable name="listener" type="MyActivity"/>
</data>
```

and in MyActivity I called a function to listen to On click from the image buttons:

```
public void onClickState(View view){
int id = view.getId();
}
```

but from some reason I don't get to this function when I click
 I tried also

```
 android:onClick="@{listener.onClickState}"
```

but nothing helped.

Comment: are you binding data in the included layout 

Variables may be passed into an included layout's binding from the containing layout by using the application namespace and the variable name in an attribute:

 <include layout="@layout/contact"
           bind:user="@{user}"/>

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html

Comment: I'm using binding with include with for first time, it is working fine, I just include the layout and use
 ```binding.included_layout.textview.setOnClickListener(....)```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Activity:

```
activityMainBinding.included.setListener(this);
```

global_actions.xml::

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable type="your.packages.here.MainActivity" name="listener"/>
    </data>

    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_black_36dp"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:background="@color/colorToolBar"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:onClick="@{listener::onClickState}"
    android:alpha="0.4"/>
</layout>
```

Comment: yes i just forgot the setListener, works great by now!!,

Comment: I can't be quiet about this problem. You saved me after days of researching. Thank you :)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 15):

If you want to use `DataBinding` variables in an included layout, you need to pass them to the included layout, and also make your parent view use `DataBinding`:

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable type="your.packages.here.MainActivity" name="listener"/>
    </data>

    <FrameLayout>
        <include
            android:id="@+id/included"
            layout="@layout/global_actions"
            app:listener="@{listener}"/>
        </include>
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

You need to set your listener in your MainActivity.class to the corresponding binding class:

```
activityMainBinding.setListener(this);
```

and in your included layout, you need to use the same name that you used in your parent layout (`app:listener`):

```
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable type="your.packages.here.MainActivity" name="listener"/>
    </data>

    <ImageButton 
     android:onClick="@{listener::onClickState}"/>
</layout>
```

Please take a look at [George Mounts answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32958608/4908802) to a similiar question.

Comment: hi, i don't think that you have to set the listener in the parent too, it worked to me without it, only in the include layout..  in the main activity i added:              mBinding.included.setListener(this);

Comment: Yes, this also works. But in that case you needed to assign an id to your `<include />`