# Android Data binding is not working for included layout

Tags: android, android-resources, android-databinding

I wanted to reuse text fields and hold them separately in XML file as independent components. I'm using data binding to bind string resources.

It worked fine if those components were not split into independent XML files, but now as I've used include tag, it is not displaying any resource strings in App. What can be wrong?

Code example:

Main layout

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="CustomRes" type="com.project.utils.CustomResources"/>
    </data>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/mainContentLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium">

           <include layout="@layout/form_name"/>

           <include layout="@layout/form_email"/>

           <include layout="@layout/form_phone"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

Included Layout example:

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="CustomRes" type="com.project.utils.CustomResources"/>
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:hint='@{CustomRes.stringValues["form_name"]}'>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Posible solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51638633/14327871

Comment: That solution is fine. I rather binded whole CustomRes into included layout like this:

`<include layout="@layout/form_name" bind:CustomRes="@{CustomRes}" />`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the ID to the `include` tag:

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/mainContentLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium">

       <include layout="@layout/form_name"
                android:id="@+id/name_layout_include"/>
       <include layout="@layout/form_email"/>
       <include layout="@layout/form_phone"/>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Included Layout example:

```
<layout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
        app:errorEnabled="true">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_et"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

Then you can address it by calling:

```
mBinding.nameLayoutInclude.nameEt
```

Since Viewbinding is more future proof than Databinding, it's better to just go this way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="CustomRes" type="com.project.utils.CustomResources"/>
    </data>

   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/mainContentLayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium">

           <include 
           app:CustomResIncluded ="@{CustomRes}"
           layout="@layout/form_name"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

and **include_layout** :

```
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="CustomResIncluded" type="com.project.utils.CustomResources"/>
    </data>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        android:hint='@{CustomResIncluded.stringValues["form_name"]}'>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/nameEt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:singleLine="true"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            style="@style/TextInputEditTextStyle"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</layout>
```