# Viewstub cannot pass stringresource to databinding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-databinding, viewstub

I am trying to pass a "@string" and "@stringarray" to my viewstub databinding via xml, but it does not work. I get the following error message:

```
C:\Users\censored\AndroidStudioProjects\example\app\build\generated\source\kapt\debug\com\example\app\databinding\AppStandardContactFormBindingImpl.java:943: error: cannot find symbol
            if (this.appDefaultCompanyNameEt.isInflated()) this.appDefaultCompanyNameEt.getBinding().setVariable(BR.hint, appDefaultCompanyNameEt.getResources().getString(R.string.app_contact_form_company_name));
                                                                                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   method getResources()
  location: variable appDefaultCompanyNameEt of type ViewStubProxy
```

### ViewStub inflated layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="vBility"
            type="Boolean" />
        <variable
            name="vForm"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="hint"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="iType"
            type="Integer" />
        <variable
            name="mText"
            type="String" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="@{vBility}">

        <com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_default_et"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@{hint}"
            android:visibility="@{vBility}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:validate_form="@{vForm}">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="@{iType}"
                android:text="@={mText}"
                android:textSize="@dimen/font_text_large" />

        </com.example.app.presentation.util.view.FixedInputTextLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### Using Layout inside viewstub

```
<ViewStub
    android:id="@+id/app_default_company_name_et"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/wrapContent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:inflatedId="@+id/app_default_company_name_et"
    android:layout="@layout/app_standard_textinputlayout"
    android:visibility="@{cValidator.companySwitchState}"
    app:vBility="@{cValidator.companySwitchState}"
    app:vForm="@{cValidator.etCompanyNameEM}"
    app:hint="@{@string/app_contact_form_company_name}" <!-- THIS IS GIVING ME THE ERROR -->
    app:iType="@{0x00000001}"
    app:mText="@{cValidator.etCompanyName}"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/app_default_company_ust_et"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/margin_left"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calibrate_user_data_company_text" />
```

When I change `app:hint="@{@string/app_contact_form_company_name}"` with `app:hint="@{someClass.someString}"` it works. Does that mean, that I can't directly pass any string to my databinding if it is a viewstub?

Answer (score 1):

This is the short answer to why you are having trouble passing a string resource into a *ViewStub*: In the code that you posted, the part that is causing a problem is `appDefaultCompanyNameEt.getResources()`. Here `appDefaultCompanyNameEt` is a [ViewStubProxy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewStubProxy) which is not a *View*, so it doesn't have associated resources. As a result, `appDefaultCompanyNameEt.getResources()` fails. The message is a little cryptic, but this is what it means.

```
if (this.appDefaultCompanyNameEt.isInflated()) this.appDefaultCompanyNameEt.getBinding()
    .setVariable(BR.hint, appDefaultCompanyNameEt.getResources()  // fails!
    .getString(R.string.app_contact_form_company_name));
```

I believe that this can be considered a bug. So what is a work-around?

It seems that greater care was taken in providing a bound data link to included files. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32958608/6287910) Stack Overflow answer from George Mount.

So, what we can do is place the contents of the *ViewStub* in an included file like this:

**view_stub.xml**

```
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="myData"
            type="String" />

    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="A hint"
        android:text="@{myData}"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</layout>
```

and reference it in a layout file that will be included in the main layout:

**included_layout.xml**

```
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="myData"
            type="String" />

    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ViewStub
            android:id="@+id/viewStub"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inflatedId="@+id/inflatedViewStub"
            android:layout="@layout/view_stub"
            app:myData="@{myData}" />
    </FrameLayout>
</layout>
```

Finally, the main layout:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/included"
            layout="@layout/included_layout"
            app:myData="@{@string/myStringData}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

If we define a string resource as follows:

```
<string name="myStringData">My string data.</string>
```

Then this layout will display

[image]

This works because the initial include does a good translation of the string resource. The included file just sees the string which it handles OK.

This is a little complicated. I would be interested to know if there is an easier way.

Comment: The easiest way to do this, is instead of using "@string/bla_bla_bla" to create another variable inside your class and then get the string from there. So @{myClass.myString}. I will post my solution tomorrow

Comment: @Andrew  I agree that would be easier, but it seems to me that you were looking to pass the string resource directly into the _ViewStub_. In any case, you turned up a bug. I will look for your answer.