# Way to do two-way data binding in Android while using <include> tag?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, data-binding, android-databinding

So the problem space is pretty simple.

I have a layout. Let's call it `fragment1.xml` and it looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="SomeViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/include_some_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/layout_consent_checkbox"
            app:checkedData="@{viewModel.checkedData}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And let layout file `layout_consent_checkbox.xml` be this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="checkedData"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb_some_data"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="@={checkedData}"
            android:text="Plis check this?"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Now according to my knowledge, this should work. `checkedData` in `SomeViewModel` should be updating the Boolean value, based on the status change of the CheckBox. But it isn't getting updated. Please have a look and update me on what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: is this different than https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag

Comment: Not really, what I'm doing is two-way databinding. I am able to do proper one-way data binding, but not two-way. Something is missing from my code.

Comment: that's fine, i remember using something like the link i've posted but i think i just needed something simpler, instead of using multiple linear layouts you could consider creating custom views for these includes and just using them all in a constraint layout instead, having all these nested linear layouts isn't very good for performance most likely