# Android Databinding in 2xml files

Tags: java, android, mvvm, viewmodel

How can I bind 2xml files using databinding?
how to provide data in textview of paymentbillingelement using viewmodel setValue property??

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
            <variable
                name="PaymentFragmentView"
                type="com.hughesnet.sa.viewModels.PaymentFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

         <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include layout="@layout/payment_billing_element" />    

      </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this there is already answered your question.
please have a look

[Android Data Binding using include tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag/32958608#32958608)